# How to run current python file in floating terminal? Using neovim and NvChad

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, linux, nvchad

FYI noob here.

I want to run current file in floating terminal. I'm using NvChad and when I execute ALT+i I get the following:
[image]

I already played with some key binds, but I haven't achieved what I need. Currently, in my ~/.config/nvim/lua/custom/mappings.lua I have the following:

```
---@type MappingsTable
local M = {}

M.general = {
  n = {
    [";"] = { ":", "enter command mode", opts = { nowait = true } },
  },
}

-- more keybinds!
M.custom = {
  n = {
    ["<C-R>"] = {"<cmd>sp<CR><cmd>term python %<CR>", "Run current Python file in terminal"},
    ["<C-W>"] = {":bd!<CR>", "Close current buffer"}
  }
}

return M
```

When I do C-R I can run succesfuly the python file but currently it goes horizontally and below my current file.

I tried `tabnew` and `split` but no luck.

By the way, from documentation I have:

- C = CTRL
- leader = SPACE
- A = ALT
- S = SHIFT
- A-i: to open a terminal in a floating tab
- A-h: to open a terminal in horizontal term
- A-v: to open a terminal in vertical term

And I'm using Linux fedora

**Any thoughts?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```
-- more keybinds!
M.custom = {
  n = {
    ["<C-R>"] = {"<Cmd>lua require('nvterm.terminal').send('py ' .. vim.fn.expand('%') .. '\\r', 'float')<CR>", "Run current Python file in terminal"},
    ["<C-W>"] = {":bd!<CR>", "Close current buffer"}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for me! @Vivian De Smedt

By the way, it's not a big deal, but when I run it I get the floating terminal and I have one line with the py file.py, and for some reason I have 2 more lines in blank like if I have pressed enter.

Comment: Oh nevermind I understood, the \\r is a special character sequence that sends a "carriage return" to the terminal. Thanks!

Comment: Oh crap, I got a new problem. When having activated a virtualenv I cannot do it, what a bummer.

Comment: Haha, never mind again! Did a noob mistake, echo $PATH was not correct.

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: PS I wouldn’t override the defaults for redo and wincmd

Comment: I agree, I just took the one proposed by the OP for the sake of clarity.

Comment: How would I implement this using nvchad such that this mapping only gets enabled in .py files?

Comment: I believe it is not possible by editing that table. I suppose you have to rely to customization and `autocmd` based on `filetype`. Probably by editing `nvim/lua/custom/init.lua`.